# Omitting 'the' in "chlorine can oxidise the bromide ions (in, for example, potassium bromide solution)"

Tags: articles, parenthesis

[From Chemguide](http://www.chemguide.co.uk/inorganic/group7/halogensasoas.html):

> In each case, a halogen higher in the Group can oxidise the ions of one lower down. For example, chlorine can oxidise **the** bromide ions (in, for example, potassium bromide solution) to bromine.

Can we omit **the** here, or does the parenthetical phrase force the use of the definite article before **bromide ions**?

My edit without **the**:

> In each case, a halogen higher in the Group can oxidise the ions of one lower down. For example, chlorine can oxidise **bromide ions** (in, for example, potassium bromide solution) to bromine.

Is this okay? Or will such parenthetical phrase always force the use of **the** where it otherwise could\would have been omitted?

---

P.S. After posting the question, I read further, and there's a sentence right after the quoted one:

> As you have seen above, chlorine can also oxidise **iodide ions** (in, for example, potassium iodide solution) to iodine.

Here, there's no **the** before "iodide ions". So the use of **the** appears to be in free varation. Even if a parenthetical construction allows one to use **the**, the definite article still could be omitted. Am I right?

Or maybe the use of the definite article here is unrelated to the content of the parentheses?

Comment: I'm a chemist. You're right the "the" is superfluous.

Answer (score 2):

The **the** in your first example is not necessary but is helpful **if** the writer is referring to **a mixture** of different ions or **a specific example**

> oxidize **the** bromide ions in the solution

not using **the**

> oxidize bromide ions

is a **general statement** about a general chemical reaction